# Not been able to keep the font in footer same size during zoom

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to keep the footer text size the same during zoom, but unable to get success. However, with similar questions on this forum about keeping the font size the same, I have been able to achieve success in the header part. I request if someone can resolve this issue.

```
<div class="footer"> 
<a id="one" href="#">link<a>
</div>

.footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 5vh;
font-size: 1rem;
}
```

`

Comment: Hi. Why do you want to do that? If a user choose to zoom it is probably for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to use **viewport units**. These units allow you to get it feeling perfect and then have that experience scale to any size screen.
HTML :-

```
<div id = "footer">This is a footer</div>
```

CSS:-

```
#footer {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 10vh;
    line-height: 10vh;
    font-size: 5vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```